# How to get the index of a selected dropdown item in a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How would I get the index number of the dropdown selection that the user picks from the form's fields? I would like to be able to save this index number to the Rails database.

```
= simple_form_for(Rule.new, html: {:multipart => true, autocomplete: "off", :class=> "form-horizontal" }, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f|
    = f.select :header, @headers.each{|header|}, {:prompt   => "Select a Header"}, {id: "ruleHeader_select"}
    br
    = f.collection_select(:rule_type_id,  @ruleTypes, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Rule Type"}, {:id => 'ruleTypes_select', style: "display:none;"})
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: '@headers.each_with_index {|a,i| puts i}' #> Will show the index of  the item

Comment: That shows the index but then how do I pass that through the form?

Comment: What the purpose of having the index of the item?

Comment: I would prefer to just pass in the names but the way the app was built before me, it parses the info based on index number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of arrays as options into `collection_select`:

```
@ruleTypes.each_with_index.to_a
```

This will show the values from `@ruleTypes` to the user, while the selected values will be indexes.